# How to Print Paired Elements Line by Line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
guessesRemaining=12
Summary=[]


code=['1','2','3','4']



while guessesRemaining > 0:
report=[]
guess=validateInput()
guessesRemaining -= 1
if guess[0] == code[0]:
    report.append("X")
if guess[1] == code[1]:
    report.append("X")
if guess[2] == code[2]:
    report.append("X")
if guess[3] == code[3]:
    report.append("X")

tempCode=list(code)
tempGuess=list(guess)

if tempGuess[0] in tempCode:
    report.append("O")
if tempGuess[1] in tempCode:
    report.append("O")
if tempGuess[2] in tempCode:
    report.append("O")
if tempGuess[3] in tempCode:
    report.append("O")

ListCount=report.count("X")
if ListCount > 0:
    del report[-ListCount:]

report2=report[0:4]
dash=["-","-","-","-"]
report2=report+dash
report3=report2[0:4]
report4="".join(report3)
guess2="".join(guess)
Summary+=[guess2,report4]

print(Summary)
```

The validateInput() calls a function which I didn't add here. I'm trying to figure out how to print my results one line at a time throughout the course of the 12 guesses. Through three guesses I recieve...

```
['4715', 'OO--', '8457', 'O---', '4658', 'O---']
```

when I want to recieve...

```
['4715', 'OO--'] 
['8457', 'O---']
['4658', 'O---']
```

I've tried to add in \n in multiple ways but I can't figure out how to implement it. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: please fix your indenting

Comment: This is for the game "Mastermind", right? I could suggest a lot of simplifications to the logic, but this isn't a code-review site...

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried to add in \n in multiple ways but I can't figure out how to implement it.

It will help a lot if you structure the data properly in the first place.

```
Summary+=[guess2,report4]
```

This means "append each item found in `[guess2,report4]`, separately, to `Summary`".

It seems that what you meant was "treat `[guess2,report4]` as a single item to append to `Summary`". To do this, you need to use the `append` method of the list:

```
Summary.append([guess2, report4])
```

Now that we have a list of pairs, each of which we want to display on a separate line, it will be much easier:

```
for pair in Summary:
    print(pair)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you require something like

```
In [1]: l = ['4715', 'OO--', '8457', 'O---', '4658', 'O---']

In [2]: l1 = l[::2] # makes a list ['4715', '8457', '4658']

In [3]: l2 = l[1::2] # makes ['OO--', 'O---', 'O---']

In [4]: for i in zip(l1, l2):
   ...:     print i
   ...:
('4715', 'OO--')
('8457', 'O---')
('4658', 'O---')
```

Answer (score 0):

if `Summary` is only intended to be printed and not used in subsequent steps,

```
Summary+=[guess2,report4,'\n']

for i in Summary:
  print i,
```

another way would be to use one of the solutions from [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)